# Can RabbitMQ consumer configure to consume only a defined number of attempts for the same message

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

Does RabbitMQ capable in a way, I can define my consumer that it has a limit of consuming the same message. i.e my consumer doing a basic Reject with enqueue=true. And it will infinitely keep on listening to the same message. I am not talking about TTL on the queue side. But a control/config over consumer to tell I want to consume this only 5 times and then send it to another queue for instance. Can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 2):

So yes I believe this can be done. You will need to cache the delivery tags of the messages received and also keep track of a reject count. Once the reject count for a particular message is great that five and then publish the message to another queue. You will also need to ACK back to RabbitMQ for the message recieved and likely create a new message (with a new delivery tag) and publish it.

Comment: Hi tkeE2036, Is there a way to keep track on reject count from broker side in rabbitMQ ? Or do I need to manually persist the status to a DB and keep track on rejected count from there.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done on application level or via [TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) and [Dead Letter Exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html). There is not known way to what you want on broker side (and I see no reason why you can't do that on consumer side)

*P.S.: just make comment more visible*

The main idea is to create custom ttl property (a-la hops count in TCP/IP packages) and decrease it every time message been consumed (and re-publish message body with new props). When it reaches zero - publish it to other queue.

Comment: TTL will say messages in this queue should leave the queue after X amount of time. This is not exactly what I want. What I want is from consumer side, to configure it to consume the same message a given number of time and then send it to a different queue. Can this be done from consumer end ? would you mind give a small example on how to?

Comment: i don't know the exact java syntax how to do that, but the main idea is to create custom ttl property (a-la hops count in TCP/IP packages) and decrease it every time message been consumed. When it reaches zero - publish it to other queue.

Comment: Hi  zaq178miami, do you know API calls to set/get the TTL from cunsumer?

Comment: Message properties can be changed (normally) only on publish. After that if you want to change props or body you have to re-publish message with new data. In you task, I guess, the only important part is message body. So you can consume message, and then publish new one with the same body and different params. More on this link https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html